# Magento Module not visible on the admin

Tags: magento

Please guide me on the below,

Magento Core Module is enabled on the admin.

System->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced.

I checked the DB, the status is enabled. I download the original source code and uploaded it. even though the module is not visible.

Its status is still showing false.

Is there anywhere status is updated other than core_config_data?

In the Cache files, It is showing the status as false.

I have cleared the cache, logged in and logged out everything. no use.

Comment: Which module are you talking about? What is supposed to do? Where is supposed to appear?

Answer (score 0):

You wanna see the Magento Core Module???? :-)
The core module is the engine of your Magento installation, you cant see it!